# Is a Motivation Letter for Employment different from the letter used while applying for a student visa?

Tags: software-industry, communication, new-job, cover-letter, visa

I am a non EU person, a third country national, and if I want to convert my student visa into a salary one, I have to write a Motivation letter for Employment to the Embassy of the concerned country where I will do my future job.

Is this motivation letter the same as what we write while applying to a student visa?
And if not, does anyone have any idea about what are the differences?

I am living in France, want to work in Belgium.

Comment: You need to give more information as too which country you are from and the one you want to work in for anyone to give you much help.

Answer (score 5):

To put it very generally, a motivation letter is written by an applicant to any such person that is reviewing his application. It is simply a letter which should encourage the reader to seriously consider the candidature of the applicant and review the person for selection.

**What Makes a Motivation Letter**

Now, the letter is not too different from a cover letter which go with resume writing; in fact a lot of people tend to get the two confused. But while both these letters are trying to highlight that the candidate feels he is well suited for the job, there is a slight distinction between the two. Firstly, it is a less formal type of letter writing than the standard cover letter. Secondly, the cover letter is just supposed to state the facts, while the motivation letter can elucidate the aptness of the writer's candidature. So we can see that the latter can be an important tool for career development.

To that end, the writer of this letter has to press on about his qualities, which he feels qualify him to be fit for the post he's sent his job application for. Such letters are often written to colleges and throw light upon the qualities that the applicant has, which may or may not be apparent in his college application.

**This is an example of a Motivation Letter:**

> During the past four years, I studied industrial engineering (with
>   specialization in?) electronics at Ostend. The emphasis of my studies
>   was understanding the fundamental electronic principles that govern
>   modern day electronics. But I also learned about other diverse topics
>   such as safety, economics, and industrial management. I found the last
>   topic, industrial management, to be very interesting and exciting,
>   because one of my career aspirations is to participate in the senior
>   management of an industrial company.
>
> To further my career aspirations of becoming part of a senior
>   management team, I want to obtain a Master's Degree in Industrial
>   Management. Having this knowledge will allow me to better understand
>   management principles. With all the uncertainty and changes in with
>   world, political, economic, and technological, I believe that
>   management must have a solid understanding, supported by a strong
>   academic foundation, of how to guide companies through these
>   challenging times.
>
> No education is complete without experience. Armed with a solid
>   understanding of academic principles, I can begin my career where I
>   will add to my experience. Because I will be well versed in the
>   theory, I will be able to adapt and modify the theoretical constructs
>   as required in order to meet my company's needs. I fully recognize
>   that our political, economic, and technological environments are
>   constantly changing, and thus management needs to be able to adapt
>   quickly and accurately to the new conditions if the company is to
>   survive, let alone prosper. I believe obtaining a Master's Degree will
>   provide the necessary background for me to be to anticipate and react
>   to ever-changing environments.
>
> I look forward to launching my new career. Should you have any
>   questions, please contact me at....
>
> Sincerely,

(Source: ["Sample of Letter of Motivation"](http://www.gotostudyabroad.com/study-abroad/documentation/letter-of-motivation/sample-of-letter-of-motivation.htm))

Comment: Michael, welcome to Workplace SE! Rather than provide links to external resources, please include relevant excerpts in your answer to prevent link rot.

Comment: Hi Deer, thank you for the welcome. I provided an example of a Motivation Letter via a link. How would you suggest I supply part of a letter example? There is no other information on the page apart from the example.

Comment: @MichaelGrubey the point is that the link may die in the future, so rather than just giving the link, it's better to give the link and paste in the sample letter saying, "Here is a sample from this link". That way if the webpage goes down in the future, the relevant information will still be there.

Comment: @jmac I see what you mean thank you for that. Will edit the post to include the sample letter.

Answer (score 0):

No, the motivation can hardly be the same, because now you are writing for an employment visum, not for a study. [That is, assuming you did not use you student visum for a job; in that case they could be the same.]
You have other reasons for wanting a job than for a study.

We cannot say what those reasons are for you.
The best you can do is ask here for example motivations (from people having been in that same position and having received either a yes or a no) that would help you get the visum.